# How to add design-time support for Enabled property in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I've created a Winforms UserControl (Visual Studio 2008, 3.5 Framework SP1).  I've been able to create some of my own public properties that Visual Studio is able to properly handle (i.e. the form designer properly reacts to changing property values).

I would like to set the Enabled property a CheckBox control according to the Enabled property of the UserControl.  This would be under UserControl1.cs:

```
 `chkMyCheckbox.Enabled = Enabled`
```

I have tried putting this both under the EnabledChanged event of the UserControl and overriding the OnEnabledChanged method, but neither seems to catch.  This is not a toolbox caching issue (b/c I can see other code changes taking effect).

Thanks in advance,
-Alan.

Comment: There's no point.  When the user control is disabled, the check box is automatically disabled as well.

Comment: I was thinking Alan wanted a checkbox whose Checked state was tied to the Enabled state of a different control.  Rereading the question again, Hans Passant's comment on the question seems correct:  If the checkbox is on the UserControl being disabled, the checkbox should also already be effectively disabled by inclusion.  I think the Enabled property on the checkbox might still read true, but the entire UserControl gets disabled when userControl.Enabled = false.

Comment: just to clarify: you know how a texbox will gray out when it's disabled? It won't do that if it's simply contained inside a user control. How can I bind the enabled property of the textbox to the enabled property of its parent control?  i want it to LOOK like it's disabled (I realize functionally it already is)

Comment: Still confused.  Is this a designer or run-time question?  At runtime, all controls on a UserControl are disabled both functionally and visually when the parent UserControl is.  At design time, controls are not graphically disabled regardless of container.

Comment: Design-time.  works at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The way a control is rendered at Design-Time is up to the designers of that control.  The core Win32 controls do not render themselves as Disabled when in the Designer.